Why do cryogenic temperatures usually result in higher conductivity, even (sometimes) superconductivity, but otherwise nonconductive Wigner crystals?
Wigner crystals are all the rage in the news, since around the start of the pandemic...
But at what temperatures (and pressures?) do these cold materials create a nonconducting 'Wigner crystal' rather than a highly conductive conduct or even a superconductors?
The recent news from Ali Yazdani's team at Princeton mentions the fact that sometimes, at extremely cold temperatures, the kinetic energy of the electrons cannot overcome their Coulomb repulsion, and conductivity slows or even stops rather than increasing....
P.S.: Did Heike Kamerlingh Anne's expect to find an 'electron crystal' when cooled his mercury wire in 1911?  How did Eugene Wigner explain this in 1934?

Kamerlingh Onnes had issues with the established Drude model/ Kelvin model, which said that the resistance goes smoothly to zero/ passes through some minimum as you lower the temperature. He believed that the vibrations of electrons would stop suddenly (at 4.2K) leading to a drop in resistance but that there would still be a small, measurable value [Freezing Physics, Dirk van Delft]
